# No debugger working with SilverLight 4 OOB (Out of Browser) app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, debugging, silverlight-oob

When I try to use the VS 2010 (Ultimate) debugger on a SL4 OOB application I get this message:

> "No Source Available"
>   No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame.  The source code cannot be displayed.
>
> To investigate further, try one of these options:
>     Browse to find Source (greyed out)
>     Show Disassembly (if I click on that it comes up with a screen saying "No disassembly available."
>     Call stack location:  (followed by empty space)

What am I missing in order to get VS 2010 to be able to debug a SL4 4 OOB app?

Comment: Explain what 'Multifate' means.  Also mention if the debugger works when you run it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it had finished executing and had "nothing to show."  This was rather frustrating for someone "new to Visual Studio / Silverlight".  Once I put a breakpoint at the startup routine I could step through and do normal debugging of the app.

Comment: just a general aversion to "Ultimate" as a marketing term to describe a product as well as a general dislike for "crippled" environments where you have to pay more $ for every little bit of "extra" functionality you may end up needing...

Comment: Your comment should be added under your question rather than your answer. Also, StackOverflow isn't the place for complaints about products. If you want help, be clear and concise so people can understand the issue you need solving.